# How to prevent a group admin from re-adding me to the same group every time I leave it?

Tags: whatsapp

Is there any way to ignore a group permanently or block it? I muted it, but it still appears on my recent list. I tried to leave, but the admin keeps adding me to it again.

Comment: This is pretty off-topic for SuperUser. I would expect blocking the admin (if possible) should be enough though.

Comment: Blocking the admin would be my guess too. I would contact [WhatsApp support](https://www.whatsapp.com/contact/) because as @MichaelFrank said, this question is off-topic.

Comment: How off-topic? I'm asking about the features of an application.

Answer (score 1):

To block a group or being invited to a group, you may block the administrator of the group. Once you have blocked the admins, they cannot invite you anymore.

Source: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/30061418